Problem Importing and Using a Vue Component in a Plugin
I'm facing an issue when trying to import and use a Vue component within a plugin. My Vue 3 project has the following structure:
I work on a large system, and we have a unique situation within our system. We are updating the application to use new technologies.
We have a back-end built with Laravel 4.2 using Blade for the front-end.
Due to the size of the system, we are creating plugins with Vue 3 to develop parts of the front-end incrementally.
We cannot refactor everything at once because it has not been approved by management and would take too long. Therefore, we are making updates gradually.
Due to the peculiarities of our project, I encountered this problem.
In the code provided in my GitHub repository, I replicated our issue.
https://github.com/Carlos-Alexandre-Leutz/erro-no-vue-3
I have a component that I use within a plugin made with Vue 3, but I also need to use this same component in another Blade page separately.
With Vue 2, everything worked fine. However, in Vue 3, when I create a main.js for Component 2, everything stops working, and no error is thrown.
Below is a detailed description of what I'm doing.
In summary, I am building the application and calling the scripts within an index.html file that simulates my Blade.
When I build only Component 1, everything works.
When I build both Component 1 and Component 2, nothing works.
But there is an important detail:
When I register a child component in Component 2, the problem occurs. If I do not register it, I can use Component 1 and Component 2 normally.
However, the components in my application have several child components within their respective Component 2, so I need help to resolve this issue.
my-project/
├── public/
│   ├── dist/
│   │   └── vue-3/
│   │       └── js/
│   │           ├── chunk-vendors.js
│   │           ├── comp_1.js
│   │           └── comp_2.js
├── src/
│   ├── Comp1/
│   │   ├── MyComponent.vue
│   │   └── main.js
│   ├── Comp2/
│   │   ├── MyComponent.vue
│   │   └── main.js
├── vue.config.js
├── package.json
├── index.html

In vue.config.js, I have configured multiple entries for comp_1 and comp_2:
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
module.exports = defineConfig({
productionSourceMap: false,
transpileDependencies: true,
filenameHashing: false,
outputDir: "./public/dist/vue-3",
pluginOptions: {
webpack: {
dir: \["./webpack"\],
},
},
pages: {
comp_1: {
entry: "src/comp-1/main.js",
filename: "comp-1.html",
title: "comp-1",
},
// Comment on this section to see the project working
comp_2: {
entry: "src/comp-2/main.js",
filename: "comp-2.html",
title: "app_comp-2",
},
// Comment on this section to see the project working
},
});

The problem occurs when I try to import Comp2 within Comp1. Comp2 doesn't work and shows no errors in the console. Here is the relevant code from Comp1:
<template>
  <div>
    <h1>Item List</h1>
    <form @submit.prevent="addItem">
      <input v-model="newItem" placeholder="New item" />
      <button type="submit">Add</button>
    </form>
    <ul>
      <li v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index">
        {{ item }}
        <v-comp-2></v-comp-2>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Comp2 from "@/Comp2/launcherComponent.vue";

export default {
  components: {
    "v-comp-2": Comp2,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      newItem: '',
      items: [],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addItem() {
      if (this.newItem.trim() !== '') {
        this.items.push(this.newItem);
        this.newItem = '';
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
Additionally, I have a component that I'm using both as a component within another plugin and as a standalone plugin:

<template>
  <div class="iconr-launcher-container">
    ico
    <div
      href="#iconr-modal-galeria"
      :class="['iconr-launcher', statusClass]"
      :style="{ 'background-image': 'url(' + launcherThumb + ')' }"
      data-toggle="modal"
      @click="openIconr($event)"
    ></div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { ref, computed } from "vue";

export default {
  props: {
    v_status: {
      type: String,
      default: "",
    },
    v_thumb: {
      type: String,
      default: null,
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const gallery = ref(false);
    const galleryShortcutsEnabled = ref(false);

    const statusClass = computed(() => {
      return "iconr-status-" + props.v_status;
    });

    const launcherThumb = computed(() => {
      return props.v_thumb === null || props.v_thumb === "null"
        ? "/plugins/dist/iconr_placeholder.png"
        : props.v_thumb;
    });

    const openIconr = () => {
      gallery.value = true;
      galleryShortcutsEnabled.value = true;
    };

    return {
      gallery,
      galleryShortcutsEnabled,
      openIconr,
      statusClass,
      launcherThumb,
    };
  },
};
</script>

When I uncomment the style section, the component stops working and shows no errors.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    component 1
    <div id="comp-1"></div>
    component 2
    <div id="comp-2"></div>
    <script src="./public/dist/vue-3/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script>
    <script src="./public/dist/vue-3/js/comp_1.js"></script>
    <script src="./public/dist/vue-3/js/comp_2.js
    "></script>
  </body>
</html>

Questions
Why is Comp2 not working when imported within Comp1?
How can I debug these issues?
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!
Additional Information
Vue version: 3.x
Build tools: Vue CLI
Relevant Code
https://github.com/Carlos-Alexandre-Leutz/erro-no-vue-3
With this detailed description, I hope to get help to resolve these issues. Thanks in advance for any guidance or solutions suggested.
Thank you!

Can you clarify what are the steps to reproduce and the exact result that you see? From the repo, comp-2 works inside comp-1 when the supplied public/dist/ is used, and the app to render at all when a new build is created with "npm build"

The specific issue:
comp_2 does not work when imported within comp_1.
comp_2 contains child components, and importing these components seems to be causing the problem.
When comp_2 has no child components, both components work correctly.
To resolve this, we have tried:
Ensuring that the import paths are correct.
Checking if the child components of comp_2 are properly registered and exported.
Analyzing the webpack configuration file for potential conflicts.
more information in readme

I cannot reproduce this and I don't see why nested comp would be a problem. It works ok with public/dist/vue-3 you commited to the repo, and none of the app renders if new build is created  with "npm build", regardless of child components in comp_2

I made this video to help you understand better
https://youtu.be/CYH_NXfn8f8

Thanks, this helped. Please, add index.html to the question as its relevant. It should contain all needed information even if external links become unavailable

The problem is that when multiple are built, this results in additional JS chunk. Since manually created index.html is used instead of autogenerated one, this wasn't taken into account.
When a Webpack chunk is not loaded, the symptoms are the same as described, the application is not started without any errors in the console.
For 2 subapps in pages, they should be loaded as:
<div id="comp-1"></div>
<div id="comp-2"></div>
<script src="./public/dist/vue-3/js/chunk-vendors.js"></script>
<script src="./public/dist/vue-3/js/chunk-common.js"></script>
<script src="./public/dist/vue-3/js/comp_1.js"></script>
<script src="./public/dist/vue-3/js/comp_2.js"></script>


Thank you very much, to note in the question, the only change I needed to make to my project, which is not the example project provided on the forum, was to add it to my vue.config
this code to generate the chunk-common.js file
  configureWebpack: {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          common: {
            name: 'chunk-common',
            chunks: 'initial',
            minChunks: 2,
            priority: -10,
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
            enforce: true
          },
          vendors: {
            name: 'chunk-vendors',
            test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
            priority: -20,
            chunks: 'initial',
            reuseExistingChunk: true,
            enforce: true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

